# PHP Warning: require_once(/var/www/html/wp-config.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/wp-load.php on line 37

Tags: php, html, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am creating an Wordpress app server on apache and I am getting an error 500 while going to the url.So, I did check the httpd/logs/error_log and the following is the error

> [Sun Jan 15 22:42:54.440349 2017] [:error] [pid 767] [client
>   10.203.116.148:9173] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/html/wp-config.php): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in /var/www/html/wp-load.php on line 37 [Sun Jan 15
>   22:42:54.440406 2017] [:error] [pid 767] [client 10.203.116.148:9173]
>   PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/html/wp-config.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/html/wp-load.php on line 37

I tried changing the file permissions for Wp-config.php but no luck, is there anything else I could do.

Comment: `Permission denied` means just that

Comment: This means that the webserver user does not have permission to open the file either by being owner of it or being assigned to the user group that owns it. Permissions should be 644 or 755.

Comment: so just using chown -a -G apache will it do it @Chris

Comment: Im not that great with linux commands so if thats going to change the user and group to the apache user and group then yes it should solve it. My apache user is www-data though

Answer (score 18):

Try changing file permissions of wp-config.php it might be given 640. Change file permission of wp-config.php or .htaccess file to 644.

Changing file permission of wp-config.php to 644 worked for me

Comment: @Lakshmi I have set permission 777 & 644 of wp-config.php file & wp-load.php file but is not working.

Comment: @SavanDholu Don't change permission of wp-load.php keep default permission only change wp-config.php file permission to 644

Answer (score 1):

This error comes most of the time after migration, So the solution is to change the permission of wp-config.php to 644. You can easily change permissions from FileZilla

Comment: Do not post external  links as unique source for answers. Post directly your code; links may become inacessible over time.

Answer (score 0):

cheek the path on wp-load.php or post it here

.